# Sharepoint online powershell script to get digest of all subsites in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, script

Is there someone who created a working script for SPOnline that lists in Excel compatible the URL of all subsites in a site collection?

Something like this

```
www.domain.com
www.domain.com\subsiteA
www.domain.com\subsiteB
www.domain.com\subsiteB\Subsite01
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - just call the last two lines for each site collection, I usually do it with a CSV list of site collection URLs from another command (can't remember the SPO one to get all site collection URLs, but it's the equivalent of Get-SpSite in server side OM) piped into a for..each loop.

Note you need to run this in a shell where you've imported the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime DLLs - if you don't have these, download them as part of the 'SharePoint Online Client Components SDK' and add lines to the top using `Add-Type` with the path to the DLLs.

```
function Get-SPOWebs(){ 
param( 
   $Url = $(throw "Please provide a Site Collection Url"), 
   $Credential = $(throw "Please provide a Credentials") 
) 

  $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)   
  $context.Credentials = $Credential  
  $web = $context.Web 
  $context.Load($web) 
  $context.Load($web.Webs) 
  $context.ExecuteQuery() 
  foreach($web in $web.Webs) 
  { 
       Get-SPOWebs -Url $web.Url -Credential $Credential  
       $web >> path\to\output\file
  } 
} 

$UserName = "yourusername@tenant" 
$Password = "yourpassword" 
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword) 

$AllWebs = Get-SPOWebs -Url 'https://tenant/site/collection' -Credential $SPOCredentials 
$AllWebs | %{ Write-Host $_.Title }
```

Comment: About your second paragraph: I was thinking of using the SharePoint online management shell. Is that ok or I still have to add those DLL?

Comment: It should work with just the SPO shell but if not, then add the DLLs.

Comment: I got errors, should I use windows powershell ISe to be able to write all of that?

Comment: the portion for authentication needs to be amended for accounts who have the multifactor authentication

Comment: Or seeing as you only need to run it as one account, just use one without MFA enabled. I don't deal with any tenants that use MFA, personally I think it's just a pain. Would appreciate it if you mark this as the answer as it does what was asked.

Comment: I have used one account that is not MFA enabled and still the powershell caused multiple errors and the excel spreadsheet is empty